# Javascript/Jquery logic regarding changing classes in different areas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure something out.  I have 10 buttons.  A button looks like the following but with different classes

```
<button id="1" class="btn active"></button>
```

Now each of these buttons are in an area.  I have defined these areas like so

```
var areaOne = [1, 2];
var areaTwo = [3, 4, 5];
var areaThree = [6, 7, 9];
var areaFour = [8, 10];
```

Now I could do most of what I need too, but I want to do it efficiently.
Each area should only have one button with the class active.
All other buttons should have the classes inactive and throb.
If an inactive button is clicked, inactive and throb should be removed and an active class added.  However, the original active button within this buttons area then needs to become inactive and have the class throb.

At the moment I have the following

```
$(".btn").click( function(){
    if ($( this ).hasClass("inactive")) {
        $( this ).removeClass("inactive");
        $( this ).removeClass("throb");
        $( this ).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

So that will make an inactive class active.  I don't know if this is the best way to do this or if it can be cleaner?  What I am not too sure of now is making the active class in the clicked buttons area inactive.  I can get the clicked buttons id, but then I need to somehow loop the buttons within this area to find the original active one and make it inactive.

How would I achieve something like this?

Thanks

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: What if you put each "area" into a `<span>` element or some such, then used that parent element as a reference point to disable all of the sibling buttons then activate the one you clicked?

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fzL6e0dr/light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a multidimensional array instead of defining them in seprate variables.

```js
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,9],[8,10]];

$(".btn").click(function(){
  // Fetch the clicked id  
  var _id = +this.id;

  // Fetch the are of the button
  var _others = arr.filter(function(v,i){
    
         return v.indexOf(_id)!=-1
    
  });
  console.log("#"+_others[0].join(", #"));
  // Make a string of others like #1, #2 and exclude this and remove class active and add classes inactive and throb
  $("#"+_others[0].join(", #")).removeClass("active").addClass("inactive throb");

  // Add class active to clicked button and remove class inactive and throb
  $(this).removeClass("inactive throb").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{background:#ff0000;}
.inactive{background:#00ff00;}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <button class="btn" id="1">Buttone 1</button>
   <button class="btn" id="2">Buttone 2</button>
   <button class="btn" id="3">Buttone 3</button>
   <button class="btn" id="4">Buttone 4</button>
   <button class="btn" id="5">Buttone 5</button>
   <button class="btn" id="6">Buttone 6</button>
   <button class="btn" id="7">Buttone 7</button>
   <button class="btn" id="8">Buttone 8</button>
   <button class="btn" id="9">Buttone 9</button>
   <button class="btn" id="10">Buttone 10</button>
```

The thing is you do not need to check befire using `removeClass("whatever")`, if it exists it will get removed otherwise won't give any error.

Comment: This seems to act a bit strange for me.  Area one for instance.  Say 1 is active, if I click on 2 it becomes active and 1 becomes inactive (as it should do).  However, if I then click back on one, one becomes active again, but 2 does not switch to inactive this time.  So it works the first time, not the second.

Comment: @kate_hudson ofcourse `2` will again switch to inactive state.

Comment: Yes, that should happen, but 1 should then switch back to active which it does not.

Comment: @kate_hudson try now. `_others` should be `_others[0]`, because on clicking `1`, what it will return is `[[1,2]]` and not `[1,2]`. Attached complete code.